# addClass if else not working properly

Tags: jquery, css

So basically, I want it to change class based on my selection. When I change it the first time, it changes class from `black` to `colored`, but when I change it back it stays both `black` and `colored`.

Can someone explain why is this happening since I remove all classes on change and then call `hover()` again, which should then apply class based on my selection. Obviously it works if I remove comments on `removeClass` method, but I don't understand why would I need it. Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
 <form>
     <select name="color">
         <option value="black-white">Black/White</option>
         <option value="colored">Colored</option>
     </select>
     <input type="checkbox" checked>Borders (on/off)
 </form>
```

jQuery:

```
function hover() {
    var color = $("select[name=color]").val();

    if (color === "black-white") {
         $("#container > div").hover(function() {
             /*$(this).removeClass("colored");*/
             $(this).addClass("black");    
         });
    } else if (color === "colored") {
        $("#container > div").hover(function() {
            /*$(this).removeClass("black");*/
            $(this).addClass("colored");
        });
    }
}

$("select[name=color]").change(function() {
    $("#container > div").removeClass();
    hover();
});
```

Comment: provide your html as well

Comment: Updated with HTML.

Comment: Where's the `#container` element?

Answer (score 2):

You can't bind event handlers inside an event handler, and expect it to change, both event handlers, and probably a lot more as you change the select, will be bound to the element, they don't go away.

You have to bind the handler **once**, and then just check the value inside it

```js
$("#container > div").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    var color = $("select[name=color]").val();

    if (color === "black-white") {
        $(this).removeClass("colored").toggleClass("black", e.type==='mouseenter');
    } else if (color === "colored") {
        $(this).removeClass("black").toggleClass("colored", e.type==='mouseenter');
    }
});
```

```css
#container div { 
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 20px;
  color: red;
}

#container div.colored {
  background: green
}

#container div.black {
    background: black
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="color">
  <option value="black-white">black-white</option>
  <option value="colored">colored</option>
</select>

<div id="container">
  <div>Hover me</div>
</div>
```